# What is the meaning of "actors" and "player" according to political terms?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, synonyms

I am reading a book where I find some sentences like

> "... how international actors impact civil wars"

> "... being a 'player' in regional politics"

> "... further study of each of the six actors' policies towards Syria"

I'm not familiar with the meaning of "actors" and "player" in this perspective.

How can I understand it clearly?

Comment: This is a specialised usage that might be better answered on [politics.se].

Comment: Actor and player here just mean “participants.” Look them up in, e.g., AHD.

Comment: “…one man in his time plays many parts . . .”

Comment: They're just metaphors, as though countries are like individuals with personalities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Words, as you might know already, have multiple denotations. According to Merriem Webster, an "actor" (in your scenario) is defined as:

> one that takes part in any affair

The affair in your situation? *Politics*. Note, however, that the meaning drastically changes in different contexts, where it *connotes* rather than *denoting*. For example, one may say:

> I don't like him; he's such an **actor**.

In this instance, the word is used to suggest that the person conceals their true identity & therefore the speaker dislikes him.